# How can I get rid of 403 "org_internal: This client is restricted to users within its organization" when trying to generate a refresh token?

Tags: google-ads-api

When I use the `generate_refresh_token.py` :

```
pipenv run python authentication/generate_refresh_token.py --client_id xxxxx --client_secret yyyy
Log into the Google Account you use to access your AdWords account and go to the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadwords&state=xxxxx&prompt=consent&access_type=offline
```

When I follow the link I get a 403 "org_internal: This client is restricted to users within its organization", I'm using a google account that has the name.surname@domain.com that matches the organization's domain and I have been invited to the project.

What else is need for my google account to be considered part of the "organization"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google account that you are using is probably a "consumer account" even if it has the same @domain.com as the organization that you are trying to use.

You need your IT admin to migrate the consumer account to the organization's Google Cloud account following the process described [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-consumer-accounts-to-cloud-identity-or-g-suite).

You will receive an email titled "Google account transfer request" prompting to authorize the transfer:

[image: Goole account transfer request]